# When I run a very simple py2exe test, it gives me errors

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I wrote a very simple program named test.py which looks like this:

```
print 'hello world'
```

then I wrote a setup program called setup.py which looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test.py'])
```

They are both in the same folder so it should work. When I run the setup.py it gives me error messages that look like this:

```
C:\Python26\lib\sets.py:85: DeprecationWarning: functions overriding warnings.showwarning() must support the 'line' argument
  stacklevel=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\program\pygametests\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    setup(console=['test.py'])
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
    raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I am running windows vista.

Comment: I believe setup.py is a system command of some sort or lives in the path.  Try changing the name of your file from setup.py to mySetup.py or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should go to the folder where you have your files and run:

```
C:\Python27\mydir> python setup.py py2exe
```

or directly

```
C:\Python27\mydir> setup.py py2exe
```

the traceback is telling you you are not sending any command ('py2exe' in my example) for setup.py in the command line

You can see available commands with:

```
C:\Python27\mydir>setup.py --help-commands
Standard commands:
  build            build everything needed to install
  build_py         "build" pure Python modules (copy to build directory)
  build_ext        build C/C++ extensions (compile/link to build directory)
  build_clib       build C/C++ libraries used by Python extensions
  build_scripts    "build" scripts (copy and fixup #! line)
  clean            clean up temporary files from 'build' command
  install          install everything from build directory
  install_lib      install all Python modules (extensions and pure Python)
  install_headers  install C/C++ header files
  install_scripts  install scripts (Python or otherwise)
  install_data     install data files
  sdist            create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.)
  register         register the distribution with the Python package index
  bdist            create a built (binary) distribution
  bdist_dumb       create a "dumb" built distribution
  bdist_rpm        create an RPM distribution
  bdist_wininst    create an executable installer for MS Windows
  upload           upload binary package to PyPI
  check            perform some checks on the package
  py2exe

usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help


C:\Python27\mydir>
```

Comment: I have been running the program straight from the file itself, now when I go to that folder in cmd, it tells me that python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: @user1429351 that is because on Windows, Python is not automatically added to the PATH variable. You will need to set it yourself by R-Clicking My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Find "PATH" in the list and add your Python folder to the of the the string, Click Ok and open a new CLI and try it again.